# Vertical Owl Carousel Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, owl-carousel

I am using Owl Carousel plugin in my website and I want to create a vertical slider with this. [Overall layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeBbg.png) for a section looks like this. I'm also using Bootstrap. However, creating a vertical slider as in the image is quite tricky part and I need your help for this.

```js
$(function() {
  var owl = $('.history .owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
    stagePadding: 0,
    margin: 15,
    loop: true,
    dots: false,
    nav: true,
    navText: [
      "<i class='fa fa-angle-up'></i>",
      "<i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>"
    ],
    items: 3,
  });
});
```

```css
.box_area {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto 50px auto;
  font-size: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  word-spacing: 0px;
}

.box_area:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

.leftarea {
  height: 500px;
}

.rightarea {
  height: 500px;
}

.rightarea img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="history">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="section_title">My Performance History</h2>
    <div class="row box_area">
      <div class="col-md-9 leftarea">
        <img class="leftarea_img" src="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 owl-carousel rightarea">
        <div class="item">
          <img class="rightarea_img" src="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="rightarea_img" src="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="rightarea_img" src="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get your code working, so i made a quick setup.

Give the images that you want on the right a `display: block;` this will make them sit underneath each other.

I hope this helps.

```css
.img-list img {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left;">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</div>
<div class="img-list">
  <img style="max-width: 20%;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  <img style="max-width: 20%;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</div>
```

Comment: Or, it doesn't have to be Owl Carousel, but should be simply made with JQuery. I'm also open for other solutions in order to get a slideshow like shown in a picture.

Comment: @rrrrrauno You can use whatever you want. But this does take some tweaking. You can use the code above to move the images to the side. I could not find a working example.